# Return next line (next string) after a regex pattern was matched? (Python)

Tags: python, regex

What I am trying to do is a pretty standard task of matching a particular result in a .HTML file. For this I am using python and wrote this code:

```
...

import re, requests

res = requests.get('http://www.website.com/page.html')

t = res.text

g = re.search("(regex)", t)
```

...

This works fine. However, my actual task is to get the string, which *follows* the string found by my regular expression. It is *always* in the following line of the .html-document. It is the whole line from start to finish, which probably makes it a little bit easier. Very unfortunately I have no way to find the right data directly with a regex.

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe `re.search(r"regex.*\r?\n(.+)", t).group(1)` if your `text` is the whole multiline string.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to iterate over the lines.

When a line matches, returns the next one:

```
import re

text = """abc
def
ghi
klm
"""

pattern = re.compile('def')

def find_following_line(text):
    lines = text.splitlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if re.search(pattern, line):
            return lines[i+1]

print(find_following_line(text))
# ghi
```